# Get window width javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to measure the width of the current viewport to set variable `thisWidth` but getting 'undefined'

```
var thisWidth;
var browserWidth = $(window).width();

if(browserWidth > 590){
    var thisWidth= 180;
} else if(browserWidth > 350){
    var thisWidth= 150;
}

alert(thisWidth); // undefined??
```

Is there a better way to do this?

The reason I am doing it is to change a width variable(thisWidth) based on viewport width whether it be mobile or whatever.

**UPDATE - SOLVED** Problem was, it was measuring before it had finished loading! Therefore coming in below 350 where finished width was 360 - weird actually

Comment: Works fine. Try remove var's inside if statement

Comment: You'll probably need a `thisWidth` too if the viewport is `<350`!

Comment: Post your solution in an answer, not the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the code inside "jQuery ready" as:

`$(function(){
   // Your code here
})`

Answer (score 0):

The `var`s are redundant since they make variables local to the **function scope**. They don't hurt, but make the code less clear.

I'm guessing you are missing a default value if `browserWidth` happens to be `> 350`

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the extra `var`s are unnecessary and can be removed. If you look at the logic, there's one case where `thisWidth` can be undefined after the if. What happens if `browserWidth` is less than or equal to 350? Then neither of the assignments to `thisWidth` will run. Add a final else to fix it.

```
var thisWidth;
var browserWidth = $(window).width();

if(browserWidth > 590){
    thisWidth= 180;
} else if(browserWidth > 350){
    thisWidth= 150;
} else {
    thisWidth=42;
}

alert(thisWidth);
```